# SCORM 1.2 and WBT Manager

Tags: scorm1.2

I'm developing a SCORM module that will then run on WBT Manager. The SCORM module is a Flash application using the pipwerks library.

But when inporting and testing my module on this LMS, I run into the following problems (note that I do not have those problems on the Moodle LMS):

- If my .swf flash file is under "/flash/..." within my module, the main index.html won't find it (404 error) whereas the URL looks right (I've tried both relative and absolute URL to the swf file). If I put the .swf file at my SCO root, it works fine.

  I also have xliff files (for translations) within my SCO but I can put them anywhere in the SCO (root or /lang/...), trying to fetch them will always return a HTTP 404 :(... Any idea why ? Is there anything I should change in my SCO manifest file to make it working ?
- I need to be able to close the browser window from my Flash SCO but calling the below javascript code from my as3 code doesn't work when running on WBT (it works when running the SCO in standalone mode, ie: not in WBT) :

  ```
          function() {
      window.close();
  }
  ```

Thanks in advance for anyone who could help...

Regards,

Tom

Comment: It seems that WBT Manager rewrites the URL when importing the scorm package. There is an option to disable it when importing but when checked, then even the index.html isn't reachable...

Answer (score 0):

I've found why it was not working...

The xliff file were not recgnized by WBT Manager because of their extension. I've changed it to ".xml" and it works fine now...